# How do I redirect in a Mojo::Exception check block?

Tags: perl, exception, http-redirect, mojolicious

Let's say I have something like this which works,

```
eval { die "asdf" }
Mojo::Exception::check(
    default => sub { die 42 }
);
```

But what I want is something like this..

```
eval { die "asdf" }
Mojo::Exception::check(
    default => sub { $c->redirect_to("https://google.com") }
);
```

I find that even up the completion of the `$c->redirect_to` that nothing happens.  Moreover, if I do something like,

```
eval { die "asdf" }
Mojo::Exception::check(
    default => sub { $c->redirect_to("https://google.com"); die 42; }
);
```

That it still dies.

So in normal code I can do

```
return $c->redirect_to("https://google.com");
```

Which will work, but how do I do that inside of a call to `Mojo::Exception::check`

Answer (score 2):

I would prefer to use [Syntax::Keyword::Try](https://metacpan.org/pod/Syntax::Keyword::Try) to catch exceptions. This solves this problem, because it does not wrap the exception handler in a subroutine so you can simply return, as well as by default avoiding the issue of [relying on truthiness of $@](https://metacpan.org/pod/Try::Tiny#BACKGROUND).

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Syntax::Keyword::Try;

sub ... {
  try { die "asdf" }
  catch { return $c->redirect_to("https://google.com"); }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I got around this by adding,

```
return $c if $c->res->is_redirect
```

Like this,

```
eval { die "asdf" }
Mojo::Exception::check(
    default => sub { $c->redirect_to("https://google.com"); }
);
return $c if $c->res->is_redirect;
```

Also,

```
09:16 < kraih> EvanCarroll: best is probably "return if $c->res->code;"
```